# How to convert a string with zeros to number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this string: `"140.000.000"`, when I try to convert it to number with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, it always give me `140` without the rest, I already tried with replacing the `"."` with `","`, but it does not work, someone can help me?

Comment: You need to replace the `.` with nothing. `140000000` is the number you need to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dots:

```js
const num = parseInt(`140.000.000`.replace(/\./gm, ''));

console.log(num)
```

Answer (score 3):

`"140.000.000"` isn't a *valid* Number, neither `"140,000,000"`. Run the code below,

```js
console.log(isNaN("140.000.000"))
console.log(isNaN("140,000,000"))
console.log(isNaN("140000000"))
```

However, `"140000000"` is. So, try replacing the `.` with empty string as,

```js
str = "140.000.000"
n = Number(str.replace(/\./g, ''))
console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str ="140.000.000"

console.log(parseInt(str.split('.').join('')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
const string = "140.000.000";
const number = parseInt(string.replace(/\./g,""));
console.log(number);
```